# Ajax Respond Internal Server Error 500 After Save in database Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have some problem when after saving into the database and redirect again, after that I use function ajax post and the response is

> Internal Server Error 500.

Comment: Increase the execution time of php

Comment: figure out why it is taking so long, increasing the execution time is a bandaid.

Answer (score 0):

Increase your execution time as the error shows clearly what is required.

set your maximum execution time to 0. which will remove it.

and increase your memory limit to 2048M

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); 
ini_set('memory_limit','2048M');
```

If you do not want to increase it for entire project. add it in your controller.